# Writing data to csv using pandas duplicated

Tags: python

I am using pandas to list all the duplicate values in my current csv. I can get it to print to the console, but I want to write it to a csv with headings so all data is sorted into columns and rows. Currently with the write output it dumps into into one column.

```
try:
 ufo = pd.read_csv('missdata.csv')
 dup = ufo.loc[ufo.Usage.duplicated(keep = False), :]
 print(dup)
 output = open('outputdata.csv', 'w')
 output.write(str(ufo.loc[ufo.Usage.duplicated(), :]))
```

Console output

```
   LocationID                      Name   Usage  EquipmentExtRef
1             125  Manchester Exchange     0.0   VirtMeter_Main   
3             125  Manchester Exchange     0.0   VirtMeter_Main   
4             125  Manchester Exchange     0.0   VirtMeter_Main   
6             125  Manchester Exchange   608.4   VirtMeter_Main   
7             125  Manchester Exchange   577.8   VirtMeter_Main   
8             125  Manchester Exchange   550.3   VirtMeter_Main   
9             125  Manchester Exchange   617.3   VirtMeter_Main   
10            125  Manchester Exchange   629.4   VirtMeter_Main   
11            125  Manchester Exchange   712.3   VirtMeter_Main
```

Comment: Can you share the outputdata.csv, too, please?

Comment: Please use  `ufo [ufo.duplicated]` to find dup rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Pandas [`to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method to save the DataFrame to a file.

```
dup.to_csv("duplicates.csv")
```